# Maven install plugin detect and uninstall previous versions of software

Tags: maven, javafx

I use Maven-install-plugin to create installer for my JavaFX application. Maven -> JFX -> native. Runs and creates an app. However, it doesn't check if there were previous versions of this app. How to add a check for previous versions and a dialog "Previous version will be uninstalled : OK/Cancel". Installer removes old app and installs new version if OK is pressed or quits of Cancel is pressed.

Comment: You would probably want to rephrase or rethink your problem as I do not think you are using the maven-install-plugin for that. http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/

Comment: This is a problem of the installer, not the maven-plugin or your IDE. When using javapackager, you can adjust your installer-script. But your question is about the installer, not the tools creating that installer